# Redirecting stdout in Python into PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, stdout

I have a pretty strange use-case here, I am trying to put together a handful of simple programs for my students that will help them learn python. To get it working I have a PyGame window embedded in a TKinter frame, and I need to redirect stdout to change something in the PyGame window. I have the redirecting working, if I redirect it to a file it works fine, but if I try to change the text it doesn't work. I hard-coded a string into the PyGame text changing code and that works, but it won't work with the redirected text for some reason.

The redirecting class:

```
class PrintTest:
    def __init__(self, file, game):
        self.f = file
        self.game = game
    
    def write(self, t):
        f.write(t)

        self.game.text = game.font.render(t, True, self.game.text_colors[1], self.game.text_colors[2])
        self.game.textRect = self.game.text.get_rect()

        self.game.textRect.center = (300, 300)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```

the game class:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        embed = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=600)
        embed.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
        if platform.system == "Windows":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

        self.text_colors = [(255,255,255),
                            (0,255,0),
                            (0,0,128)]

        # initialize a pygame display
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
        self.screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        self.font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
        self.text = self.font.render('Hello, world!', True, self.text_colors[1], self.text_colors[2])
        self.textRect = self.text.get_rect()

        self.textRect.center = (300, 300)

        # TK Creation
        helv = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight='bold')
        self.button = tk.Button(root, 
                                text="Change text",
                                font=helv,
                                command=self.change_text).pack()

        self.user_input = tk.StringVar()
        self.textbox = ttk.Entry(root, width=15, textvariable=self.user_input)
        self.textbox.pack()
        # ---------------------------------------------------------------

    def change_text(self):
        print(self.user_input.get())

    def run(self):
        # Pygame loop
        running = True
        while running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False

            self.screen.fill(pygame.Color('red'))    

            self.screen.blit(self.text, self.textRect)

            pygame.display.update()

            try:
                self.root.update()
            except tk.TclError:
                running = False   
        pygame.quit()
```

and I set up the stdout like this:

```
try:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('1000x600')

    game = Game(root)

    f = open('text.txt', 'w')
    sl = PrintTest(f, game)
    sys.stdout = sl

    game.run()
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    pygame.quit()
```

When I run this as it is, if I type hello in the box, hello is printed to the file, but a null character is put into the pygame box. I don't really know PyGame well enough to know if it is an issue on that end or a redirecting issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(In case you are wondering what the use-case is here, I am going to have them 'finish' some programs to make something happen in PyGame. So if they type print('Hello Friend!') into the given field, it will redirect that to be dialog for someone in the PyGame box. It may not work in the long run, but I gotta get past this to really figure that out)

Edit:

So the problem is that the write function is being called twice for some reason when I click the button, it is calling print on the typed in string then again on an empty string. Still not sure how to fix it, but at least I found the problem

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem. Your title says `TypeError`, you write something about when you _"try to change the text it doesn't work",_ but also that it does work but there's a null character appended to the display (or does it display just the null character?). What's the main problem you have? If you have an actual error message, then please include it in the question. Also, make sure your indention is correct in the question.

Comment: There isn't exactly a typeerror, I shouldn't have put that as the title, that was an error I was getting but it wasn't the problem. The problem is that the string being passed to my stdout replacement prints fine when added to a file, but when I try to modify the PyGame string it just prints a null character. The typeerror came from when I was trying to print the type of t in the printtest class. Sorry about the indention, the text input on here is not particularly nice about adding indentation after moving the code into it

Comment: Have you tried printing `t` in `def write(self, t)`? Does it contain just the null character? If so, then you know that the problem isn't pygame, but with the redirection. I haven't done much redirections like this, but my guess is that `t` is an iterator and gets consumed on `f.write(t)`

Comment: I would need to reset the stdout to the console to try that, which is why I pushed it to a file. The file shows the right text, so I am fairly certain is isn't the redirection

Comment: I was wondering about that too, but even when I remove f.write(t) it still shows the null character

Comment: Do you happen to know what type `t` is?

Comment: Just checked, it's a string

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a character that the tkinter entry widget is adding to that the end that PyGame can't display. Edit: Just checked that, got a substring and still didn't display it

Comment: That would be if "Helvetica" has characters "freesansbold" doesn't, which seems unlikely. It's weird that `t` is a string and doesn't work, while hardcoded strings in the `write` method do work. Are you sure that you've confirmed both these correctly? If so, I'm not sure what the problem can be

Comment: Yeah, I confirmed it again just to make sure. If I hard code 'Hello' it changes it, but using t does nothing but show a box. I am wondering if it has anything to do with font being the old way to use text in pygame, going to try to use freetype instead and see if that works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I figured out the problem, it is calling the write function twice for some reason, once on the typed in string and once on an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I found the problem.

It looks as though print sends two things to stdout, the string to print and the ending character. So it was overwriting the string I wanted printed with a newline character. I changed my PrintTest class to accommodate for this:

```
class PrintTest:
    def __init__(self, file, game):
        self.f = file
        self.game = game

    def write(self, t):
        if t != '\n':
            self.f.write(t)
            self.game.text, self.game.textRect = game.font.render(t, self.game.text_colors[2])

            self.game.textRect.center = (300, 300)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```